# Error en sub Menú del explorador de soluciones de Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

estoy en una clase de MVC con la versión 5.0 e net, el profesor usa la versión Enterprice de VS para enseñarnos y veo que a él y a otros compañeros al hacer clic derecho les sale las opciones para agregar directamente para agregar clase y no como a mi que tengo que colocar nuevo elemento e incluso ni me sale la opción de controlador que a él, me sale solo el controlador genérico.
Es un nuevo curso y aunque le he preguntado, me dice que talvez se deba a mi versión de Visual, pero cambié al profesional y es igual, sigo todos los pasos que me indica.

Ayuda, por favor.

[image: Visual Studio no me muestra las opciones de agregar controlador, clase, etc.]

[image: VS le muestra las opciones de agregar controlador, clase, etc. directamente al hacer click derecho y se muestra en la barra explorador se muestran más opciones.]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Herramientas > Personalizar...> Comandos > Menú contextual > Menús contextuales de proyectos y soluciones|**Proyecto**. Luego clic en restablecer todo. Puedes agregar los comandos y menús a mano pero es tedioso. Cerrar y listo.